# Brief explanations of using pyqt5 slots, signal, emit() and connect()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

For the past few months, I have been using pyqt5 and I have used some of the answers to the questions here as a helping hand for coding.

While reading the answers, I have seen a lot of time the usage of pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot, emit() and connect (), which I have been trying to understand for a while, but almost every time I think I have figured it out, I realized my assumption was wrong.

So to put it simply, and I know this is probably a really hard/general question (English isn't my mother tongue, I mean like, a question that needs specifications since it has a large amount of answers), but could anyone help me understand it with a little bit of either information of using it/examples of using the pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot, emit() and connect()?

I appreciate the time you took to read, and thank also to all of those who can help.

Comment: What are you unsure about, exactly? PyQt5 provides bindings to Qt5, so I would recommend reading the original documentation, which is quite good. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html I can also recommend _Martin Fitzpatrick_'s resources https://www.pythonguis.com/pyqt5-book/

Comment: Also note that Qt6 - PyQt6 and PySide6 - has been out for some time now. But that's neither here nor there.

Comment: This kind of information can easily be found online in various basic tutorials: e.g. [Zetcode: Events and Signals in PyQt5](https://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt5/eventssignals/) & [ReaPython: Event Loops, Signals and Slots](https://realpython.com/python-pyqt-gui-calculator/#event-loops).

Comment: The question is a bit too generic, can you try to improve it by explaining what "wrong assumptions" you believe you're making?

Answer (score 0):

> `pyqtSlot`

Named `Slot` in PySide.
**It is just a function.**
Why do we call it Slot then?
Well that is because when you declare a function as a Slot,
Qt saves some info about it so we would be able to call dynamically in the future. [Read more here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/metaobjects.html).

> `pyqtSignal`

Named `Signal` in PySide.
You can think of it as a messenger,
when you tell it to send a message (by `emit`) It will call all of the functions (slots) that you connected to it.

> `connect`

Registers a slot to a signal.
So that every time that signal is emitted that slot will be called.

> `emit`

Tells a signal to call his connected slots.